# Codeigniter passing data from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

As per [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) I've got the following controller:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function Login()
    {
        //$data->RedirectUrl = $this->input->get_post('ReturnTo');
        $data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );
        $this->load->view('User_Login', $data);
    }

    //More...
}
```

and in my `User_Login.php` view file I do this:

```
<?php print_r($data);?>
```

which results in:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: views/User_Login.php
Line Number: 1
```

Do I need to load any specific modules/helpers to get the $data variable populated? If I `print_r($this)`, I can see a lot of stuff but none of my data except in caches

Edit: To clarify, I know that calling the variable the same in the controller and view won't "share" it - it's out of scope but in the example I linked, it seems to imply a `$data` variable is created in the scope of the view. I simply happened to use the same name in the controller

Comment: I'd note that it looks like you actually used their test data from the user guide. Just a bit further down the view page you will see a section called "Adding Dynamic Data to View" which shows how to work with what you pass in. See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, the `$data` array's keys are converted into variables: try `var_dump($title);` for example.

EDIT: this is done using [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Comment: Damn - I feel like I should've spotted that. Thank you!

Comment: i  have read detailed guide about how to pass value from controller to view in codigniter  http://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 6):

you should do it like :

```
echo $title ;
echo $heading;
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use it like array.
In Controller:

```
...
$this->load->view('User_Login', array('data' => $data));
...
```

In View:

```
<?php print_r($data);?>
```

will show you the Array ( [title] => My Title [heading] => My Heading [message] => My Message )

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a variable in the url to

```
function regresion($value) {

    $data['value'] = $value;
    $this -> load -> view('cms/template', $data);
}
```

In the view

```
<?php print_r($value);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the variable $data as it is an associative array....you may print every element of the associative array.....consider the following example.

Don't do as follows:

```
echo $data;
```

Do as follows:

```
echo $title;   
echo $heading;    
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way also

```html
$data['data]=array('title'=>'value');
    $this->load->view('view.php',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

while sending data from controller to view we pass it in array and keys of that arrays are made into variables by code codeigniter and become accessible in view file.

In your code below all keys will become variables in User_Login.php

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function Login()
    {
        $data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',       //In your view it will be $title
               'heading' => 'My Heading',  //$heading
               'message' => 'My Message'  //$message
          );
        $this->load->view('User_Login', $data);
    }

}
```

and in your User_Login.php view you can access them like this:

```
echo $title;
echo $heading;
echo $message;
```