# CodeIgniter passing data to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass from my controller to the view like so...

```
public function playerslist()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $data = $this->db->get('skaters');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('playerslist', $data);
    }
```

and in my view...

```
<?php echo $data; ?>
```

but I get this **error...**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/playerslist.php
>
> Line Number: 76

What am I doing wrong?

What I would like to do with this data is put in a foreach statement and display everything in the $data array

```
foreach($data as $value => $key){
echo $key . "<br/>";
}
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter passing data from controller to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257736/codeigniter-passing-data-from-controller-to-view)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access `$data` directly from your view. The `$data` you pass to your view has to be an associative array. The keys will then be converted to variables in your view.

For example:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'bars' => 23
);

$this->load->view('playerslist', $data);
```

Then, in your view, those will be converted to variables:

```php
<?php echo $name; ?> has <?php echo $bars; ?> bars of chocolate.
```

---

If you want to access the data in its original format, pass *that* into the associative array:

```
$data = $this->db->get('skaters')->result();
$this->load->view( 'playerslist', array('data' => $data) );
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, Then how would I go about taking my db->get into the view? so I can display my data

Comment: It worked but when I tried to do a foreach statment in my view for the $data, it returned this conn_idResource id #13
result_idResource id #14
result_arrayArray
result_objectArray
custom_result_objectArray
current_row0
num_rows1
row_data

Comment: @user1269625 - You have to call `result()` on your query. See my 2nd update.

Answer (score 1):

based on your question and sample code, I conclude that you want to retrieve data from a table 'skaters' and display it in view.

```
$this-> db-> get ('skaters'); //not return result object or array
```

You need to change the code

```
$ this-> db-> get ('skaters') -> result (); // return object
```

or

```
$ this-> db-> get ('skaters) -> result_array (); //return array
```

check this link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function.
Then codeigniter will extract the second parameter using 'extract' function http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

```
public function playerslist ()
     {
         $ this-> load-> database ();
         $ data = $ this-> db-> get ('skaters') -> result ();
         $ this-> load-> helper ('url');
         $ this-> load-> view ('playerslist', array ('data' => $ data));
     }
```