# Assocative array working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, web

One question in my mind is teasing me how this is working internally.

I have a controller like **TestController** and I have passed and assocative array to my view named **TestView**. Assocative array is like.

```
$options = array(
          'small'  => 'Samsung',
          'med'    => 'Apple',
          'large'   => 'HTC',
          'xlarge' => 'Nokia');
```

I am loading the view with above array.

```
$this->load->view('TestView', $options);
```

inside the view I can access these Assocative array Index as vairables. Like

```
echo $small;
echo $med;
echo $large;
echo $xlarge;
```

I am confused how this is working.

Comment: Just a note I would name controller like Testcontroller.php and `class Testcontroller extends CI {}` first letter only upper case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter passing data to the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270330/codeigniter-passing-data-to-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood you question, you're asking about how CodeIgniter implemented this feature.

Take a look at the php function [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), CodeIgniter uses it to make the array indexes available as variable in  view context.

You can see codeIgniter Loader class (system/core/Loader.php) at line 949

```
extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. you provided me exact answer of question. Thnaks again

Answer (score 0):

[reference link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html)

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function. Here is an example using an array:

```
<?php

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

   function index() {

     $data['todo_list'] = array('Clean House', 'Call Mom', 'Run Errands');

     $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
     $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";

     $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
  }
}
```

above example $data associative array each key is converted into variable in view page .it has been done by php [extract](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp) function its codeigniter flow.

**view page:**

```
<?php

   print_r($todo_list);
   echo $title;
   echo $heading;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That appens because in all the "loader methods" in system/core/Loader.php you call _ci_load, which inside use the following code to extract the variables from the array and cache them:

```
/*
     * Extract and cache variables
     *
     * You can either set variables using the dedicated $this->load->vars()
     * function or via the second parameter of this function. We'll merge
     * the two types and cache them so that views that are embedded within
     * other views can have access to these variables.
     */
    if (is_array($_ci_vars))
    {
        foreach (array_keys($_ci_vars) as $key)
        {
            if (strncmp($key, '_ci_', 4) === 0)
            {
                unset($_ci_vars[$key]);
            }
        }
        $this->_ci_cached_vars = array_merge($this->_ci_cached_vars, $_ci_vars);
    }
    extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);
```

The important point is extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);. This is a standard php function which import all the elements of an array to the symbol table of the current scope of the process; so it create a new variable for each array element.