# Passing value from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a query in my model using joins and returned the query results as array

```
result_array();
```

I then returned that result to my controller where i called the model.

```
$data = $this->Model->show();

        foreach($data as $val)
        {
        $arr[$val['recipename']] = $val['componentname'];
        }

        if($data != null)
        {
        $this->load->view('Admin\success',$arr);
        }
```

I didnt originally had $arr value. I just added it up there to make the array clearer. Anyhow, with or without.

`var_dump($data)` and `var_dump($arr)` or even if i `$recipename` or `$componentname` stll null.

returns null. says they are undefined.

I don't know what went wrong.

I read this other question. that is why i made the $arr so i could make it a single array and so when it transfers it will be extracted and tried to echo them but to no avail.

[Codeigniter passing data from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257736/codeigniter-passing-data-from-controller-to-view)

EDIT:

query works fine, it returns values.

```
$sample = $this->db->select('recipe.recipename,component.componentname')->from('recipe')
               ->join('recipecomponent','recipe.recipeid = recipecomponent.recipeid')
               ->join('component','component.componentid = recipecomponent.componentid')
               ->group_by('recipe.recipeid')
               ->get()
               ->result_array();

                return $sample;
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `$this->Model->show();` returns anything?

Comment: probably shouldn't be using a model called model.

Comment: $arr is out scope in the if statement - unless you have declared it outside of this code

Comment: I only used model name for simplicity sake its different on my code and yes i used print_r() for every action before it goes through the $this->load->view and they have values. Its only null after its passed on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you pass an array of data to your view the **array keys are turned into variables**.  Say for example after your `foreach` loop your `$arr` variable is an array like this

```
array [
    'cheese' => 'brie'
    'cookie' => 'chocolate chips'
]
```

You would then access `$arr['cheese']` by doing the following in the view

```
echo $cheese;
```

Trying to access `$data` or `$arr` in the view won't work because they are not in scope

Comment: $recipename and $componentname is undefined. 

I made $arr assoc array for that purpose to try it out and it failed.

Comment: But remember its the value in `$val['recipename']` that will become the variable name.  So if `$val['recipename']` contains a string called "recipe_one" then `$recipe_one` will become the variable name in the view

Comment: Ahh, this was the solution. I understood the extraction wrong for assoc arrays.

so the variable name would be the [key] in my assoc so if my key is [key1]=>number 1

echo $key1; would result to 'number 1'

Comment: How would i then echo if the array is this

Array ( [0] => Array ())

It gets extracted, so obv the key would be 0. I just can't print_r($0); now can i?

Comment: A solution i came up with is ill wrap it in another array with a definite key name $arr = array('info'=>$data);

so on the view ill just have to loop $info. or create_Table($info);

Comment: I just realized, $this->table->generate(); takes the first values and  adds them as <th>. Theres no way of customizing it right? 

anyways, is there a way i can choose not to extract the array when passing to the view?

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is most likely empty and you are iterating an empty array.

A simple way to debug is found below:

### Debugging an array or object:

```
echo '<div style="padding:15px; background-color:white;"><pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre></div>';
```

**or**

```
echo '<div style="padding:15px; background-color:white;"><pre>'.print_r($this->Model->show(), true).'</pre></div>';
```

You should also turn on error reporting in your `__construct` like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If the `print_r()` shows you an empty array then your model is returning no data and the answer to your question is probably that you need to fix your query.

Comment: The query works fine. As i said, i used print_r for every action before i loaded the view and it printed out an array of values from my query. i will include my query on the question to clarify this.

Comment: I see. Lol this makes me think of something I once read: `When I want 100 answers then I'll ask the 50 people that I work with. When I want the correct answer then I read the manual/docs/instructions.` **[CI Views](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)**

Comment: I misunderstood the extraction part of CI when passing an array of data to the view.

Well, i guess i wouldnt have had to ask this question if i only read it. 

documentation really is important huh

Comment: Yep but don't sweat it. I just like to pass along that anecdote every once in a while :)