# How to keep past values when form is refreshed?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When an application form is submitted there are some required fields missing. How can I keep the filled values in the relevant text boxes when it is refreshed? The code needs to be in CodeIgniter.

Code for the text box creation is as follows:

```
<?php
$data = array(
"name" => "catname",
"id" => "catname",
"value" => "",
"required"=>"required",
"class" => "form-control",
"placeholder" => "Category Name",
"aria-describedby" => "sizing-addon1"
);
echo form_input($data);
?>
```

Comment: Check codeigniter form validations user guide

Comment: Assign the form value in session, and placed in value to set the session value

Comment: useful? [Codeigniter passing data from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257736/codeigniter-passing-data-from-controller-to-view)

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, catch the values and put them in $_SESSION variables.
Then you can send them in your form after your page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

send post data to view :-

```
//in Controller
$data=$this->input->post();
$this->load->view('viewname',$data);
```

you can use this data in view .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_value` helper function. Documetation given [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
<?php
$data = array(
"name" => "catname",
"id" => "catname",
"value" => set_value("catname"), //This is the change
"required"=>"required",
"class" => "form-control",
"placeholder" => "Category Name",
"aria-describedby" => "sizing-addon1"
);
echo form_input($data);
?>
```